# Right way to animate children inside custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am building a custom `ViewGroup` that arranges a bunch of children in particular positions.

On a particular trigger (lets say an external button press), the children animate to new positions. The way I tried doing it was by starting a Timer and on each timer update, computing new positions and then calling `requestLayout()`.

When I do this the animation is a little jittery. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Any ideas on what the right steps are to do a custom rearragement of child views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) like this:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(R.android.anim.slide_in_left);
anim.setAnimationListener(listener);
view.startAnimation(anim);

private AnimationListener imageViewAnimationListener = new AnimationListener() //
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) //
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) //
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) //
    {
    }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will work. I think this needs to be called in conjunction with requestLayout at the end of the animation.